# Object detection code in Tensorflow issue - AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, tensorflow2.0, python-3.7

I am using tensorflow 2.0, python 3.7 on Linux. I am trying to run the object detection tutorial code from the following repository:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection

The block of the code throwing the error is provided below.

```
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef() 
  with tf.compat.v2.io.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS, use_display_name=True)
```

If I run the last line, it is showing the error mentioned in the title. Please provide the solution

Edit: Added the screenshot of the issue[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1MEK.png)

Comment: Seems to be a protobuf issue. Can you verify.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @Ghost. I faced the similar issue in the previous block. But the problem was the compatibility of the code with Tensorflow 2.0. It was fixed with a minor change. Like `tf.GraphDef` was replaced by `tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()`. Here the issue is inside the function `create_category_index_from_labelmap`.

Comment: PS: I have added the screenshot in the original description